# Why could Rails be losing user session information after a redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a weird nondeterministic bug. When my user signs up for the first time, I do sign_in(:user, user) and then a redirect_to '/'. Before the redirect, I am logging user_signed_in? and it always shows true.

Now, in the controller route for '/', I am calling user_signed_in? and it sometimes returns false, directly after having returned true!

This happens much more often with short passwords.

I have checked there are no save errors on the user, and also that the passwords are long enough to pass Devise's checks.

What could be causing user_signed_in? to return true, and then SOMETIMES switch to false?

I have tried to put a breakpoint in https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L123

but weirdly the breakpoint seems to be executed BEFORE the polymorphic code has been customised for user:

[image]

Comment: Is user getting logout on redirect?

Comment: This is exactly my question! Usually, the process works fine and the user is still logged in after the redirect. However, especially when I use a shorter password, they are logged out after the redirect. How could this be happening and could it be a race condition (because timing)?

Comment: May be user creation getting rolled back because of validation

Comment: The user already exists, it's just having its password changed. As I noted, there are no validation errors - I used save! and also checked there were no errors.